# What is the i with a dot on top and dot on bottom called?

Tags: vowels

I was watching a foreign film and I saw a "i" with a dot on the top as usual and a dot on the bottom. What is it called and is there a way I can find it and type it?

More details:
It was a Vietnamese film published by a French company. I think it was Vietnamese text.

Comment: It's called a `Latin Small Letter I with dot below` and is Unicode U+1ECB: ị. How you type it is system-dependent. Because this is not about English, it's rather off-topic, I think.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I was about to agree with you and vote to close, but then I realized this is a question asking for an English word for a foreign glyph. Not so sure it's off-topic.

Comment: And there is no vietnamese.stackexchange.com...

Comment: Thank you for keeping the question open and understanding!

Comment: http://shapecatcher.com/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's English it's called an *underdot*. It is a *diacritical mark* much as acute accents and umlauts are. In Unicode it is referred to as "dot below".

In Vietnamese, it's used to represent a particular tone, as Vietnamese is a tonal language where tone affects meaning and so it is good to reflect it in spelling.

Note that in `ị` the underdot is considered a diacritical mark, but the dot above is not; it is considered part of the `i` itself.

How to type it depends on your keyboard. One type used in Vietnamese would type it by pressing the key that is in the position `9` is on English-language keyboards, followed by the letter wanted for `ạ ẹ ị ọ ụ ỵ` (a "dead key" method to diacritics, as on physical typewriters the key wouldn't move the paper). It's combined with other dead keys for `ặ ậ ệ ộ ợ ự`.

In Unicode, it can be encoded either by "precomposed characters", or by following the vowel with "combinging dot below".

Answer (score 3):

The dot below the letter *i* is a [*diacritic mark*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_%28diacritic%29) — *dot* is actually the correct term for the kind of mark it is.

In the case of Vietnamese, it denotes the *nặng tone* (low, glottal), used on the base vowels: ạ ặ ậ ẹ ệ ị ọ ộ ợ ụ ự ỵ

How you type it is system and keyboard dependent.

Comment: It's not "combining dot below", that's a unicode character used for one particular way to encode it in computing. `ị` for example does not use combining characters, and the term isn't used outside of computing contexts.